# Provide separate Android Manifests per Android API

Tags: android, android-manifest

After moving to target API 28 one of the features of my app requires

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

Is there a way to provide different manifests per API version? or to remove that permission in the Manifest for older versions?

Already tried

```
android:maxSdkVersion="integer"
```

But that only works if you don't want the permissions on newer Android version and not vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can per se.  You could probably setup your primary app module as a library, then create other modules, as application modules, that have the desired AndroidManifest.xml.  This would lead to multiple different apps, though, where each application module has a different package name.

Can you provide more context, though, on why you want to do this?  It might help yield a better answer from the community based on your specific needs.

Comment: sure, our app uses WifiInto to fetch the current network name (SSID), After Android 29 in order to get that info we need that Coarse location permission. But is not necessary for older Android devices 28 or older. That's why we wanted a separate manifest per Android version (specifically Android 29)

Comment: I'm not familiar with any way to make the Manifest version specific.  I can see where having one less permission would make users happier / feel safer.  However, what if the user upgraded to 29 later?  Would the new Manifest be used then?  I just don't think Google separated things out that way.  I'm still thinking you're only way of doing this would be a core module with the majority of your app and then wrapper modules that pulled in the core & used different package names & manifests.  But, that means multiple app listings on the Play Store.